# Problems using local jar in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a project i export to jar file and install with maven:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/myuser/workspace/libs/mylib.jar -DgroupId=br.com.mylib -DartifactId=mylib -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

In other project i just import in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.mylib</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This works fine, if i use this setup in pom.xml of "mylib":

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.mylib</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MY LIB</name>
```

Now i want to change for 2.0 version, like this:

```
  <version>2.0</version>
```

But when i remove the SNAPSHOT word nothing works, if i use "1.0" without SNAPSHOT i can't import this library in another project, the error is : ClassNotFoundException like jar aren't imported.

My pom.xml of "mylib" project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.mylib</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <name>MYLIB</name>
  <description>any description here</description>
  <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE
        </org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>


  <!-- JASPER REPORT IMPORTS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
            <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
            <version>1.5-beta1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- FIM JASPER RESPORT IMPORTS -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>20040616</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2.m2</id>
            <name>Java.net m2 repo</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
            <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>jwebbuild</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'nothing works' ? could you show an error log from a maven build?

Comment: maven build didn't show any error. When i try to start server the error apper: ClassNotFoundException like i didn't putted the mylib in pom.xml

Comment: did I get you right that you get an exception in case your dependency is version `2.0` while dependency version `1.0` works fine?

Comment: Yeah, exactly this. If i try use 1.0-SNAPSHOT everything works fine, if i try use 1.0 or 2.0 without SNAPSHOT the server throws the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: could you show the whole POM of the other project which uses the dependency?

Comment: I edited my post adding the pom.xml of "mylib" project

Comment: Now I've really lost you. `mylib` is a dependency project, right? Why does it have packaging `war` if it's a jar library you want to import?

Comment: Well, this works with 1.0-SNAPSHOT, i don't think that format is the problem.

Comment: first of all - @SergeyPauk is correct. the "packaging" should be "jar", or removed at all as "jar" is the default. Second, did you make sure you built the "mylib" in version:2.0-snapshot, BEFORE you tried to use it as dependency in another project?

Comment: @Shelly could you add a complete POM  of your main project as well (I mean the one which uses `mylib` as a dependency)?

Comment: can u paste the pom.xml of the project that uses mylib ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. @SergeyPauk is correct. the "packaging" should be "jar", or removed at all as "jar" is the default.
2. did you make sure you built the "mylib" in version:2.0-snapshot, BEFORE you tried to use it as dependency in another project? in "mylib"'s pom I see that the version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT. If you want to change to 2.0, then first of all you have to change mylib itself to 2.0, build it and install to the local repo, and only then try to use it as dependency in another project.
3. the right way to use maven's versions is to use SNAPSHOT version during development, e.g. X-SNAPSHOT, and only after you finish development (i.e. releasing the product) you change the version to X

Comment: and did you BUILD mylib:2.0 ?

Comment: can u paste in your question the pom.xml of the project that uses mylib ?